# Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined in service Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm doing http-request to server in one service and then I want to extract response in other service. And if response is wrong I want to redirect user on error page.

**DataService.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import './../rxjs-operators';
import { Json } from './models/json';
import { ResponseService } from './providers/response.service';
import { ErrorService } from './providers/error.service';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    constructor(private http: Http,
        private responseService: ResponseService,
        private errorService: ErrorService) { }

    getData(): Observable<Json> {
        return this.http
            .get(this.getDataUrl)
            .map(this.responseService.extractData)
            .catch(this.errorService.handleError);
    }
}
```

**ResponseService.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Json } from './models/json';

@Injectable()
export class ResponseService {
    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    extractData(response: Response) {
        let json: Json = response.json();
        if (json.status === 'success') {
            return json.data;
        } else {
            let errorId: number = json.data;
            console.log(this.router);
            this.router.navigate(['something-went-wrong'], { queryParams: { errorId: errorId } });
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

But I have error `Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined` and when I print `router` in console I see `undefined`.

How can I resolve that?

Comment: Change `.map(this.responseService.extractData)` line with something like `.map(this.responseService.extractData.bind(this))` or `.map((res)=>{return this.responseService.extractData(res);})`

Comment: Thanks, it helped me

Comment: Exactly my problem, thanks